# How to display executed test count summary in Gradle?

Tags: testing, gradle, junit

When a test fails Gradle prints at the end a summary line like:

> 15 tests completed, 1 failed

When all tests are successful however, this line isn’t printed.

Is there a way to configure it being printed upon a successful test run as well?

I am using Gradle version 6.6.1. Tests are run with JUnit Platform and implemented with Spock Framework.